# jooq generates not compiled code from Postgres procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, java-8, jooq, postgresql-9.4

Now I am trying to use JOOQ in new version of program that communicate with 2 DBs simultaneously. But problem is coming from Postgres procedures which I cant deactivate cause of `Routine generation cannot be deactivated`, even if I don't need them in my program.

**Problem 1**

Jooq understand some procedures like a tables. I am not pro with SQL so I don't know why this happens, maybe cause of procedure return type? Code for generate one of procedures that have this "bug":

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dblink_get_notify(IN conname text, OUT notify_name text, OUT be_pid integer, OUT extra text)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
'$libdir/dblink', 'dblink_get_notify'
  LANGUAGE c VOLATILE STRICT
  COST 1
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION dblink_get_notify(text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Maybe cause of problem is fact that there is another procedure with the same name, but without IN parameter:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dblink_get_notify(OUT notify_name text, OUT be_pid integer, OUT extra text)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
'$libdir/dblink', 'dblink_get_notify'
  LANGUAGE c VOLATILE STRICT
  COST 1
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION dblink_get_notify()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

**Problem 2**

Some generated classes from procedures have compile errors (procedure above have this bug too [image])

I will give you another example:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bt_page_stats(IN relname text, IN blkno integer, OUT blkno integer, OUT type "char", OUT live_items integer,
OUT dead_items integer, OUT avg_item_size integer, OUT page_size integer, OUT free_size integer, OUT btpo_prev integer,
OUT btpo_next integer, OUT btpo integer, OUT btpo_flags integer)
  RETURNS record AS '$libdir/pageinspect', 'bt_page_stats'
  LANGUAGE c VOLATILE STRICT
  COST 1;
ALTER FUNCTION bt_page_stats(text, integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

JOOQ understands this procedure as a routine. But generated code have identical twice `Parameter<Integer> BLKNO` field. And what I found *strange* is constructor of that class:

```
/**
 * Create a new routine call instance
 */
public BtPageStats() {
    super("bt_page_stats", Public.PUBLIC);

    addInParameter(RELNAME);
    addInOutParameter(BLKNO);
    addInOutParameter(BLKNO);
    addOutParameter(TYPE);
    addOutParameter(LIVE_ITEMS);
    addOutParameter(DEAD_ITEMS);
    addOutParameter(AVG_ITEM_SIZE);
    addOutParameter(PAGE_SIZE);
    addOutParameter(FREE_SIZE);
    addOutParameter(BTPO_PREV);
    addOutParameter(BTPO_NEXT);
    addOutParameter(BTPO);
    addOutParameter(BTPO_FLAGS);
}
```

Look at double addOutParameter(BLKNO)!

Wooh, think thats all. Hope you can help me with that problems :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ran into bug [#4055](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4055). As of jOOQ 3.6, overloaded table-valued functions generate code that doesn't compile.

> But problem is coming from Postgres procedures which I cant deactivate cause of Routine generation cannot be deactivated, even if I don't need them in my program.

That's true, but you can exclude them from the code generator explicitly by name, e.g. by specifying:

```
<excludes>dblink_get_notify|bt_page_stats</excludes>
```

[More info about the code generator configuration can be found here](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration/)

Comment: `overloaded table-valued functions`, yep, I saw this bug when googling, but  in **problem 2** (bt_page_stats) jOOQ understands this as a **routine**, maybe you will find another bug :)

Comment: @invis: Oh, interesting, I missed that. Is there any specific reason why you chose to use that syntax for the `IN OUT` parameter? I.e. to separate it as `IN blkno` / `OUT blkno` with two times the same name? That's probably the reason. I'll investigate: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4570

Comment: @invis: Hmm, is this possible only with `LANGUAGE c`, perhaps?

Comment: As our DBA says: `bt_page_stats` is a function that generated from `pageinspect` extension.

Comment: OK, that's weird. Well, I suspect that jOOQ could just skip those functions that it cannot generate for these reasons... There's a similar function in the pg_catalog: `pg_stat_get_activity`. I suspect this is just some syntax quirk as the function is really a table-valued function just the same...

Comment: In my case jOOQ don't generate class for `pg_stat_get_activity`.
So ok, I just exclude this two db functions from generator and all fine. But there is the ways to improve jOOQ, good luck :)